# error while opening my sample ruby-on-rails app through terminal on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

myself new to ruby on rails, started over a tutorial to build a sample image. Using ruby 2.2.2 & rails 4.0.2 on ubuntu 14.04. Pushed ma code to heroku through git. while I try to open my app through terminal on heroku, the following error occurs [Opening shrouded-woodland-7828... **[0714/131509:ERROR:nss_util.cc(94)] Failed to create /home/udhay/.pki/nssdb directory.
]** 
i surfed a lot regarding this issue but could'nt find a soultion. Could anyone help me out?

Comment: Is that an error in your browser? NSS is the library that handles TLS ("HTTPS") connections in Chrome & Firefox. The error references the home directory on your Ubuntu machine and doesn't appear to be on the Heroku side.

Comment: no, the error occurs in terminal as /.pki/nssdb directory coul not be found, while i try to launch my app in heroku through terminal

Comment: Are you seeing this via `heroku logs --source app` or is this part of the git push process? The `/home/udhay/` part indicates it's a local problem.